# How to pull saved images from Parse.com into my app

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I would like to save some images in Parse Server and like to pull it down into my iOS app. Any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a PFImageView where you'd normally use a UIImageView. Give it the PFFile for the image you wish to display, then call loadInBackground.

```
PFFile *imageFile = [pfObject objectForKey:@"image"];
PFImageView *imageView = [[PFImageView alloc] init];
imageView.file = imageFile;
[imageView loadInBackground];
```

Comment: You should be able to double click on a File column to upload a file.