# Fetching Image from Parse class

Tags: uitableview, parse-platform, fetch

Beginner here guys. I already managed to get the text from Parse class to table view. In the same class i have another column where I put the associated image file and somehow i could not get the image file. I will be glad if you can help me with this issue. Parse class name is News and the column i would like to get is imageFile. Here is my code.

.h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
#import "TableCell.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate> {

NSArray *events;
}
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *newsTable;

@end
```

.m file

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "TableCell.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize newsTable;


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
[self performSelector: @selector(retreiveFromParse)];

}

- (void) retreiveFromParse {
PFQuery *retrieveEvents = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"News"];
[retrieveEvents findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        events = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:objects];
    }
    [newsTable reloadData];
}];
}

//*********************Setup table of folder names ************************

//get number of sections in tableview
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
// Return the number of sections.
return 1;
}

//get number of rows by counting number of folders
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return events.count;
}

//setup cells in tableView
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath             *)indexPath {

//setup cell
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"EventCell";
TableCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

PFObject *tempObject = [events objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

cell.TitleLabel.text = [tempObject objectForKey:@"Event"];

return cell;
}


//user selects folder to add tag to
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
NSLog(@"cell tapped");
}



- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

My Cell.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Parse/Parse.h>

@interface TableCell : UITableViewCell
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *TitleLabel;


@end
```

My cell.m

```
#import "TableCell.h"

@implementation TableCell
@synthesize TitleLabel;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
if (self) {
    // Initialization code
}
return self;
}



- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
[super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

// Configure the view for the selected state
}

@end
```

Comment: Hi this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17090732/how-to-pull-saved-images-from-parse-com-into-my-app) might help you out. Anything else let me know !

Comment: Thanks for the info. But I couldn't understand how to implement this into my code.

Comment: Just after `PFObject *tempObject = [events objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.TitleLabel.text = [tempObject objectForKey:@"Event"];
`
Write below lines..
`PFFile *imageFile = [tempObject objectForKey:@"image"];
PFImageView *imageView = [[PFImageView alloc] init];
imageView.file = imageFile;
[imageView loadInBackground];


`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just after

```
PFObject *tempObject = [events objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.TitleLabel.text = [tempObject objectForKey:@"Event"];
```

Write below lines..

```
PFFile *imageFile = [tempObject objectForKey:@"image"];
PFImageView *imageView = [[PFImageView alloc] init];
imageView.file = imageFile;
[imageView loadInBackground:^(UIImage *img,NSError *error){

    if(!error)
    {
        UIImageView *yourImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
        yourImageView.image = imageView.image;
        /*OR*/
        cell.imageView.image = imageView.image;
    }
}];
```

This might get you going.

Answer (score 0):

This will fetch the associated file and put it in  cell.imageView, which is a PFImageView (the Parse edition of UIImageView):

```
 PFObject *tempObject = [events objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
 cell.TitleLabel.text = [tempObject objectForKey:@"Event"];   

 PFFile *imageFile = [tempObject objectForKey:@"imageFile"];
 if (imageFile) {
     cell.imageView.file = imageFile;
     [cell.imageView loadInBackground];
 } else {
     cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"AvatarPlaceholder.png"];
 }
```

Comment: Well thanks for the answer but after i tried this i am getting a SIGABRT error : Unknown class PFImageView in Interface Builder file.

Comment: Does the code find PFImageView when you write it? It is part of the Parse API. And do you really mean the interface builder file? Does the code accept PFImageView *imageView = [[PFImageView alloc] init]; ?

Comment: Code finds PFImageView. Looks like API works fine. But yes interface builder cannot find it. i have seen some others had the same issue from walle84's link.

Comment: I can't find any of that in the link...? What is the error you get?

Comment: I had the same error that is discussed in this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17768514/receiving-error-unknown-class-pfimageview-in-interface-builder-file-for-parse) , but now i managed to make it work. Thanks again for the support.